# Big Oh and Big Theta relations confirmation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I just want to confirm these statements,

I know that Big O, and Big theta, are partial order and equivalence relations respectively, all positive integers, but not sure on these restrictions.

$f:N \rightarrow R^+$

where $f$ R $g$ is and only if $f(n) = O(g(n))$
This is still a PO (Partial Order)

where $f$ R $g$ is and only if $f(n) = Θ(g(n))$ 
This is still a ER (Equivalence Relation)

Thank you!

Comment: **NOTICE**: I've cleared many comments from this thread. Please keep tangential discussion in the chat and out of the comments. All the discussion was on (equivalent but different) definitions of $O$ and $\Theta$. Further, if one would like to answer the question, please feel free to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Big-Oh is a partial order, and Big-Theta is an equivalence relation. One can say that $f < g$ if $f \in O(g)$ (or $f = O(g)$, alternate notation-wise).

Notice though that $\sin(n) \in O(n)$ and $\cos(n) \in O(n)$, so that with this order we have $\sin(n) < n$ and $\cos(n) < n$, but we have neither $\sin(n) < \cos n$ nor $\cos(n) < \sin(n)$. This is why it's a partial order (as opposed to a total order).

The equivalence relation $f \sim g$ iff $f \in \Theta(g)$ is, as you've called it, an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting worried there with the heated discussion